# how to sleep accurately in a while loop in C (Linux)?

Tags: android, c, sleep, precision

In a C code (Linux OS), I need to sleep accurately inside a while loop - say, 10000 microseconds for 1000 times. I have tried usleep, nanosleep, select, pselect, and some other methods with no success.
Once in ~50 times it would sleep %100 longer (~20000 us).
I need to perform an action after each delay. So, each delay has to be very accurate.
Is there a way to do accurate sleeps for this case?
Thanks..

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct timespec t0, t1;
    long err;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 1000) {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t0);
        usleep(10000);
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t1);
        err = (long) ((t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) * 1e6
                + (t1.tv_nsec - t0.tv_nsec) / 1000) - 10000;
        printf("i = %d err = %ld\n", i, err);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

RESULT (log_file):

i = 0 err = -146
i = 1 err = -207
i = 2 err = -8
i = 3 err = -4
i = 4 err = -22
i = 5 err = 31
i = 6 err = -45
i = 7 err = 9
i = 8 err = 61
i = 9 err = -71
i = 10 err = -24
i = 11 err = 14
i = 12 err = -12
i = 13 err = -32
i = 14 err = -15
i = 15 err = 42
i = 16 err = -51
i = 17 err = -19
i = 18 err = -12
i = 19 err = 4
i = 20 err = 12
i = 21 err = -36
i = 22 err = -38
i = 23 err = 18
i = 24 err = 1
i = 25 err = -21
i = 26 err = -37
i = 27 err = 31
i = 28 err = -4
i = 29 err = -45
i = 30 err = -37
i = 31 err = 20
i = 32 err = -10
i = 33 err = -5
i = 34 err = -12
i = 35 err = -5
i = 36 err = -10
i = 37 err = -12
i = 38 err = -2
i = 39 err = 14
i = 40 err = -34
i = 41 err = -10
i = 42 err = -6
i = 43 err = 15
i = 44 err = -34
i = 45 err = -12
i = 46 err = -15
i = 47 err = -25
i = 48 err = 11614
i = 49 err = 2340
i = 50 err = 589
i = 51 err = 12254
i = 52 err = -93
i = 53 err = -19

Comment: Please let us see what you tried using `usleep()`. This is not a realtime OS, but I can't believe it's off by a that large amount.

Comment: Are you sure that the delay of 200 msec you indicate depends by the usleep function? Have you verified that this delay doesn't depend by ISR (interrupt sub routines) or other kind of system events?

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry, for the wrong numbers. Due to the log file, error is still high (about 50% when i = 212).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers.. Still no success..

Answer (score 0):

Sleep for a shorter period of time, then poll a high frequency counter to complete the delay. Base all the delays off an original reading of the counter to prevent drift over time. For example, previous_count = counter(), wait_count = previous_count + delay_count, delay until counter() - wait_count >= 0, previous_count += delay_count, ... . If the desired frequency is not an exact multiple of the counter() frequency, then use a variable for the fractional part of the delay (I call this remainder_count).

Since you mentioned Windows, here is an example of a thread running at a fixed frequency, and Windows XP compatable, where a Sleep(1) can take up to 2 ms. dwLateStep is a debug aid, incremented every time a cycle takes too long (it will catch up if possible). The delays are based on an original reading of the counter (using uWait, uRem, uPrev, uDelta), so there's no drift over a long period of time. This is basically how games implement a fixed frequency physics thread. Note that .net framework is not used for these type of games because it intermittently pauses a process in order to repack paged memory. Such games will set the physics thread priority higher than normal to keep other threads or processes from interfering with it.

```
typedef unsigned long long UI64;        /* unsigned 64 bit int */
#define FREQ    400                     /* frequency */
DWORD    dwLateStep;                    /* late step count */
LARGE_INTEGER liPerfFreq;               /* 64 bit frequency */
LARGE_INTEGER liPerfTemp;               /* used for query */
UI64 uFreq = FREQ;                      /* process frequency */
UI64 uOrig;                             /* original tick */
UI64 uWait;                             /* tick rate / freq */
UI64 uRem = 0;                          /* tick rate % freq */
UI64 uPrev;                             /* previous tick based on original tick */
UI64 uDelta;                            /* current tick - previous */
UI64 u2ms;                              /* 2ms of ticks */
UI64 i;

    /* ... */ /* wait for some event to start thread */
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&liPerfFreq);
    u2ms = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart)+499) / ((UI64)500);

    timeBeginPeriod(1);                 /* set period to 1ms */
    Sleep(128);                         /* wait for it to stabilize */

    QueryPerformanceCounter((PLARGE_INTEGER)&liPerfTemp);
    uOrig = uPrev = liPerfTemp.QuadPart;

    for(i = 0; i < (uFreq*30); i++){
        /* update uWait and uRem based on uRem */
        uWait = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) / uFreq;
        uRem  = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) % uFreq;
        /* wait for uWait ticks */
        while(1){
            QueryPerformanceCounter((PLARGE_INTEGER)&liPerfTemp);
            uDelta = (UI64)(liPerfTemp.QuadPart - uPrev);
            if(uDelta >= uWait)
                break;
            if((uWait - uDelta) > u2ms)
                Sleep(1);
        }
        if(uDelta >= (uWait*2))
            dwLateStep += 1;
        uPrev += uWait;
        /* fixed frequency code goes here */
        /*  along with some type of break when done */
        /*  otherwise, this example runs for 30 seconds */
    }

    timeEndPeriod(1);                   /* restore period */
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried also your method. Sorry, no success. I am not a professional programmer, but it seems to me that while doing operations the program tries to free up the memory, which slows down the process..

Comment: If the process is being paused to repack freed memory, try to preallocate the memory you need in advance, and avoid doing any further free's or allocations of memory. If this is due to other apps running, there's not much you can do (assuming you can't increase the priority of your program).

Comment: could you explain me how can I preallocate the memory for this specific case?

Comment: @ayadev - If you're program can run with a fixed or maximum amount of memory, allocate all of it at the start of the program and don't free any memory until program exit. You may need to create some sort of internal memory management within your program.

Comment: I have edited my question again. You can compile the code yourself to see the results for your OS, mine is windows 7. I don't know how to allocate memory for int, long and timespec variables.. can you show me an example that works for you? Thanks..

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Is there any similar method that can be used for android OS? Sorry, I should have stated it in my question.

Comment: @ayadev - I'm not familiar with the android OS. Are there any games for the Android OS that would require a fixed frequency physics engine?

Comment: I don't really know if there is such a game for android OS. I am actually developing an app that replays touches. It requires high precision timer to function properly. Because during a long press touch events are sent  to the input device with ~10000 us time interval. And I need to repeat this interval when I replay. When the duration is long enough, say 20 secs, then the accumulated error is measured in seconds, which is unacceptable in most cases.

Comment: What about the heart beat sensor that some smart phones have? How accurate is that?

Comment: I don't know about this sensor. But there are android apps that monitor heart rate using camera.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-heart-rate-monitor/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/heart_rate_monitor/HeartRateMonitor.java here is an example how it works..

Comment: as I see it measures the time difference inside onPreviewFrame method, which is specific for apps that use camera.