# Get precise time in 8086 dos assembly

Tags: assembly, dos

I'm making a pong game in assembly for ms-dos using video mode 13h. I need to add a delay of 1/60 seconds between each frame. I tried using interrupt 1A with AH=0 to get the system time but this only changes 18.2 times per second (so my framerate will be 18.2 fps). How can i measure time more precisely?

```
gameloop:

mov     ah, 0
int     1ah         ;get system time
cmp     dx, prevt
jz      gameloop
mov     prevt, dx
```

Comment: In the bad old days, this kind of programming was hardware dependent. Lots of people used busy loops for timing. Another option would be `int 15h`, which waits the specified number of microseconds (with a 976 us granularity), but is only available on the 286-based and newer systems.

Comment: @Cody, that's a good point, such as if you try to play old games on modern bare-metal and the game is over before you even fully depress a key :-) These things are best played in emulators where it can also emulate a much slower CPU.

Comment: To go far beyond the 18.2 times per second read [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101035/a-low-tech-approach-to-measuring-game-speed)

Comment: @GovindParmar I've rolled back your edit because it is about getting precise time in a program running under MS-DOS specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is real mode DOS running on a PC, you can use timer 0 (8254 channel 0) for a busy loop. It's a fast timer. You'll probably need to hook into INT 8, since there's an issue when the timer wraps around. I don't remember all the details, but if an INT 8 occurs during the instructions to read the timer, you need to read it again.

Info from the comments I have on an old assembly timer routine:

```
;       Timer based on 8254 channel 0 and system timer interrupt (8)    ;
;       Channel 0 runs at 1.19318 mhz or 838.0965 nsecs / cycle         ;
;       System timer interrupts every 65536 cycles = 54.925 ms          ;
;       or about 18.2 interrupts / second                               ;
;       1 ms   = 1193.18 cycles                                         ;
;       1 hour = 65536 * 65536 cycles = 3599.59 secs                    ;
```

Link to an example of code that runs at a fixed frequency with no drift over time. It's in C, and it uses sleep(), which in your case you would just loop, but you'll get the idea of how to get code to run at a fixed frequency:

[how to sleep accurately in a while loop in C (Linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600621/how-to-sleep-accurately-in-a-while-loop-in-c-linux/29602865#29602865)

Comment: Update - If you're only using timer 0  (8254) for a fixed frequency around 60 hz, then you don't need to worry about INT 08, as that's used to provide an upper 16 bit count to create a 32 bit counter. You also don't need to worry about wrap-around, if you subtract old - current (it's a count down timer) to get elapsed time. For 60 hz, you want a total of 19886 + 20/60 (19866 + 1/3rd) cycles between each 60hz cycle.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you probably *don't* want a 1/60s delay between frames (i.e., end of one frame to start of the next).

What you *probably* want is that delay from the start of one frame to the start of the next. Or, put more simply 60 frames per second (fps).

---

Having an tick cycle less than that does not *actually* limit you to a lower frame rate unless it's the actual tick causing your rendering code to run (such as with an interrupt).

You can use a bit of trickery to get a higher frame rate by using an adaptive wait loop.

It's been a while since I touched (non-ARM) assembly so I'll explain in pseudo-code. I'll also use a tick cycle of 20/sec (see addendum for how to handle other rates) to simplify the math here.

What you need is a loop that renders frames *as fast as possible* but, somewhere in that loop, include the code for a wait loop:

```
reg1 = busyTime + 1
while reg1 != 0:
    reg1 = reg1 - 1
```

Now the only trick is to figure out what the value of `busyTime` should be, to get the correct frame rate.

Since you *have* a base time and current time available to you, and you can actually *count* the frames you render, you can work out the current frame rate with:

```
tps = 20
fpsRate = frameCount * tps / (currentTime - baseTime)
```

The `tps` or ticks/second variable allows you to work in seconds as current and base time are in ticks and it's easier to think in seconds.

> As an aside, I'm actually using this exact calculation in my current work task to figure out the FPS rates we can get out of our embedded system (~74fps with vsync, which isn't too bad).

So, it's then a simple matter to adjust `busyTime`:

- if `fpsRate` is less than sixty, decrease `busyTime` but no lower than zero.
- if `fpsRate` is greater than sixty, increase `busyTime` but disallow overflow.
- if `fpsRate` is exactly sixty, leave `busyTime` alone.

This way, the busy loop will auto-adjust to the correct duration to maintain the desired frames per second.

The only tricky bit I found when doing the calculations was the fact that, at 50fps, my numbers got pretty big rather quickly.

Since I was only really interested in the last ten seconds or so, I could adjust the values on the fly to avoid overflow. A simple adjustment for that could be:

```
// Once we have eleven seconds of data,
//   strip away the first second.

while currentTime - baseTime >= tps * 11:
    // Get rid of frames.

    frameCount = frameCount - fpsRate * tps

    // Get rid of time.

    baseTime = baseTime + tps

// Then calculate new FPS and adjust busy loop.

fpsRate = frameCount / (currentTime - baseTime)
switch (fpsRate):
    < 60: busyTime = busyTime - 1
    > 60: busyTime = busyTime + 1
```

This is effectively having a "queue" of data that is at most ten seconds long. It's not *actually* a queue since it doesn't maintain the individual counts, instead using the average to adjust data. But, other than that, it behaves like one.

---

Addendum: It's also relatively simple to handle figures like 18.2 ticks per second with integers only.

Just work on five-second boundaries rather than one-second boundaries (18.2 ticks per second is exactly 91 ticks per five seconds):

```
// Once we have twenty seconds of data (four
//   five-second slots), strip away the first
//   five seconds (one slot).

tp5s = 91
while currentTime - baseTime >= tp5s * 4:
    // Get rid of frames.

    frameCount = frameCount - fpsRate * tp5s

    // Get rid of time.

    baseTime = baseTime + tp5s
```