# Assembly measure the user typing time

Tags: assembly, io, emu8086

How should I measure user typing time in assembly 8086x?

I want to write a program that prints a random word in a 10-dimensional (array[10], there will be 10 words) string array and measures the time it takes the user to enter this word from the keyboard.

I'm sorry terminology mistake, I want to say string array like c#, java as below

[StringArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcNUn.png)

When the program prints string, the program waits to enter the word from the user and when user press the keyboard timer start and stops when the user press the button enter.

Could you please give advice on how should I measure that? How could I use the timer and interrupt, could you please share guide documents or sample code?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you really mean "*a 10-dimensional string array*"? Or rather something like `array[10]` ?

Comment: I mean array[10] there will be 10 words.

Comment: 10-dimensional means `array[a][b][c][d][e][f][...][j]`, with 10 indexes, one for each dimension.  To describe what you have, say "a random English word from an array of 10 strings".  ("word" has a specific technical meaning in x86, a 2-byte chunk).  Or do you mean each `word` is a pointer to a string?

Comment: I'm sorry terminology mistake,
I want to say string array like c#, java as below,

https://ibb.co/HdKx1Fv

Comment: If you have improvements to your question's wording, [edit] to change it.  The point of comments is to suggest *improvements* to the question, not just to complain about it.

Comment: Do you want to measure each of the ten strings separately? 
If the method `Int 21/AH=2Ch`  is not precise enough, look at [Get precise time in 8086 dos assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945568/get-precise-time-in-8086-dos-assembly). The chosen platform `emu8086` isn't much appropriate for exact timing, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

The term **word** has a specific meaning in assembly language - it is a datatype of two-byte memory location which may be interpreted as a 16bit number or two ASCII characters or anything else you like.
Also *10-dimensional (array[10], there will be 10 words)* is unclear. One-dimensional array is a sequence of adjacent words. Two-dimensional array can be mentally visualized as a table with rows and columns, three-dimensional array as a cube and so on.

It looks like you need to reserve memory just for 10 bytes, where each byte of this one-dimensional array will hold one character (not word) entered from keyboard.

From the tag `emu8086` I deduce that you will use 16bit code and BIOS or DOS functions.
Current time is available by DOS function [Int 21/AH=2Ch](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2703.htm).
In order to read characters from user I recommend to check if a key is pressed by BIOS function [Int 16/AH=01h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1755.htm)
and if so (`JNZ KeyIsPressed`), use [Int 16/AH=00h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm) to read the character to `AL`, store it into your array with [`STOSB`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/stos:stosb:stosw:stosd:stosq) and loop back to a key check.
Be sure to read and store current start-time before the loop and initialize `ES:DI`
to point at your array, e.g.

```
MOV AX,@DATA  
MOV DS,AX
MOV ES,AX
MOV DI,offset array  ; ES:DI now points to the array[0].
CLD                  ; Let DI increment after each STOSB.
```

Also check if `DI` is beyond the array ([`CMP DI,array+10`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp)) and leave the loop when it's equal or above. Then get the stop-time, subract start-time and you're done.

Comment: `les di, [array]` only works if the memory at `ds:array` holds a 32-bit far (seg16:ofs16) pointer to the array.

Comment: Also, the array consists of WORDs, so `CMP DI,array+10` should probably be `CMP DI,array+20`.

Comment: @zx485: The question says it's a "string array", so I'm pretty sure they mean each string is an (English) word.  Remember, it's a typing program.  (I already commented on the question to tell them how they could have explained clearly what they actually have).  Although a string array normally means pointers, so yes it would be an array of `word` elements.  So after choosing a random word for the user to type, you'd maybe `scasb` after each input until they correctly get to the end?

Comment: @ecm You're right, I fixed it and replaced `LES`.  Thanks to @Peter's comment I can see now that @embedded_master probably wants his program to prompt the user with a random **lexical word** (short string of characters)  and then measure the time it takes for the user to repeat the prompted word verbatim on keyboard.  `REPE CMPSB` could be useful to check whether the word was exactly typed.